# open subsets of $\omega_1+1$

Tags: general-topology, ordinals

Let  $ω_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal and $ω_1+1$ together with the order topology. Let $U$ and $V$ two disjoint uncountable set consisting of non-limit ordinals, then

1. $U$ and $V$ are open and  2. $ω_1$ is the only point in the intersection of their closure.

A limit ordinal is an ordinal number which is neither zero nor a successor ordinal, the other ordinals are isolated or non-limit ordinals. My first question is, what means that $U$ and $V$ consisting of non-limit ordinals?

and why two statement above are true?

Comment: I think proposition 2 is false. Define $U$, $V$ such that
$$U=\{\lambda + 2n+1 : \lambda\text{ is countable limit ordinal, $n$ is natural number.} \}$$
$$V=\{\lambda + 2n+2 : \lambda\text{ is countable limit ordinal, $n$ is natural number.} \}$$
Then $U$, $V$ is disjoint subsets on $\omega_1$ and (maybe) it does not contain any limit ordinal. But closures of $U$, $V$ has $\omega$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is some ordinal which is not a limit, then either $\alpha = 0$, which is isolated, or it has a predecessor $\beta$ with $\beta+1 = \alpha$, and in that case $\{\alpha\} = (\beta, \alpha+1)$, which is open in the order topology. So all non-limit ordinals are isolated points, and so sets only containing them are open (as unions of the singletons).

The latter point is not true, as $U$ could contain all even numbers $2n \in \omega$, and the other all $2n+1 \in \omega$, and then $\omega$ would be a common point of their closures.

Comment: please see [Topological Groups and Related Structures](http://books.google.com/books?id=B785AETmFKEC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) p 349. example 6.1.12.

Comment: Yes, but there he should have said that $\omega_1$ is in the closure of $U$ (which *is* true) and any $G_{\delta}$ that contains that point, contains a tail of the set $\omega_1$, and this tail intersects $V$, while $V$, being open and disjoint from the closure of $U$, is *disjoint* from $\overline{U}$. Contradiction with the definition of a Moscow space: no $G_{\delta}$ can contain $\omega_1$ and be contained in $\overline{U}$. The example is correct, the reasoning is not.

Comment: I meant "$V$, being open and disjoint from $U$, is disjoint from $\overline{U}$".

Comment: why $\omega_1\in \overline{U}$? or similarly
 for $\overline{V}$?

Comment: Or in general why Every $G_\delta$-set in $\omega_1+1$ containig the point $\omega_1$ has an non-empty intersection with every uncountable subset of $\omega_1$ ?

Comment: @TXC any uncountable set $A \subset \omega_1$ has $\omega_1$ (as a point of $\omega_1+1$) in its closure: a basic neighbourhood of $\omega_1$ looks like $(\alpha, \omega_1]$, for some $\alpha < \omega_1$, and as $A$ cannot be a subset of $[0,\alpha]$, as this set is countable (recall that all ordinals $< \omega_1$ are by definition countable) and $A$ is uncountable.

Comment: @TXC Also, if $U$ is a $G_\delta$, say $U= \cap_n O_n$ that contains $\omega_1$, it must similarly contain sets $(\alpha_n, \omega_1]$, where $(\alpha_n, \omega_1] \subset O_n$. But then $\beta = \sup_n \alpha_n$ is also a countable ordinal (union of countable ordinals is a countable ordinal...) and $(\beta, \omega_1] \subset U$. So again, an uncountable subset $A$ of countable ordinals cannot be all below $\beta$ and so intersects $U$.

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma: Thanks a lot.